# Can you use wildcards when declaring variables in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, avaudioengine

I'm learning coding through building a Soundboard app. I am using `audioEngine` to play some sounds after I've changed the tunes a bit. In my `viewDidLoad`, I declare my `variables`:

```
var audioFile1 = AVAudioFile()
var audioFile2 = AVAudioFile()

if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PeteNope", ofType:
        "mp3") {
        let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        setPlayerFile(filePathURL)

    }
if let filePath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Law_WOW", ofType:
        "mp3") {
        let filePath2URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath2)

        setPlayerFile2(filePath2URL)

    }
func setPlayerFile(_ fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let file1 = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

        self.audioFile1 = file1


    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
    }
}

func setPlayerFile2(_ fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let file2 = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

        self.audioFile2 = file2


    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

then I connect the `nodes` as follows:

```
audioEngine.attach(pitchPlayer)
audioEngine.attach(timePitch)
audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile2.processingFormat)
audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile2.processingFormat)
```

So, my question is, since the variables are identical with the exception of a number, is there a way to write this programmatically so that I do not have to declare the `nodes` individually.

Comment: I don't see any `nodes` here. Which variables do you mean? Do you know `Array`s exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a lot of resources of the kind 
"PeterNope" and "Law_WOW" and want to quickly add them as nodes.

You code can be refactored as follows to add so many resources as you'd like:

```
var resources = ["PeterNope", "Law_WOW", "otherResource1", "otherResource2", ...]

func setPlayerFile(_ fileName: String) {
    // make sure resource exists and break if not.
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "mp3") else {
        print ("resource file \(fileName) does not exist")            
        return
    }

    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    // open file from resource
    do {
        let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
    }

    // connect nodes
    connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: file.processingFormat)
    audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: file.processingFormat)
}

// connect all resources
attach(pitchPlayer)
audioEngine.attach(timePitch)

for index in 0..(resources.count - 1) {
    setPlayer(resources[index]
}

// or quicker and swiftier:
resources.forEach { setPlayerFile($0) }
```

I recommend reading about for loops and control flow in general: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the resources I can start reading up on!